# Python: Inherit from a class from containing class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

When I am running the following code:

```
class A(object):
    class B(object):
        pass
    class C(object):
        class D(A.B):
            pass
```

I get an error on creating class `D`:

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

Is it possible to create `D` which inherits from `B` without extraction of any class outside `A`?

Comment: `A` doesn't exist until it's definition is complete - what exactly are you trying to do - why are you nesting in that manner?

Comment: Nesting is not a good solution in Python, as the inner classes can't access the outer class attributes.

Comment: @JonClements I'm trying to use class `A` to organize another classes. Something similar to `c++` namespace. I have a lot of classes like `B` and `C` and I want to create a few categories for them.

Comment: @NO_NAME That's what *modules* are for... put the related classes in separate modules

Comment: @JonClements I do not know python very well. I'll read about it. Anyway, question is the question and I will willingly read answers. Perhaps there is some interesting workaround to my problem.

Comment: @JonClements OK, I already know that I've used `modules` before. I don't decided to use them now, because they need to be in separated files. 
Now I found the solution: `packages`.

Comment: @NO_NAME you need to state what you need to achieve here, not just what you've tried. Why do you want this behaviour?

Comment: @RobertGrant I wrote it in the comment above. However, I do not expect to know what I should do instead of what I'm asking. I just wanted to know if this particular method can work.

Comment: I guess the raw answer, then, is no.  You can't reference `A` before its defined (which is what you're trying to do as per Jon Clements' original comment).  And you can't reference B without A if you don't move it outside A, so no, you can't do what you're trying to do.  As you've prohibited any other answers about things you might want to try and decline to say why or what you're trying to do, I doubt you're going to get many interesting answers.